# MySQL date comparison

Tags: mysql

Dates are stored in DB as such: "2011-05-26 11:00:00" in a datetime field. I'd like to find all rows where the date is greater than the first of this month, ie: 2011-05-01 09:00:00

The date formats in the DB can not be changed. What MySQL function can I use to convert the date in the DB to a format that can handle comparison? I'm guessing the best format for "first of the month" is a unix timestamp?

The time values in the dates are always present but only office hours, so from 09:00 to 17:00.

Comment: What do you mean by "this month"? Should this be considered as current month?

Comment: Posted on wrong question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's stored in a `DATETIME` field, just query on `WHERE date > '2011-05-01 09:00:00'`.

Comment: @deceze... What if the date is generating dynamically? If next time date id 2001-06-12 05:00:00? How will you calculate the first date of this date?

Comment: @Awais That's quite a separate question, but it's not hard to find the first of the month in PHP and format it with `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`. See @George's answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
$firstDayOfMonth = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0,0,0,date('n'),1,date('Y'));
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` >= '$firstDayOfMonth'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps?

```
$oDateTime = new DateTime();
$sQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= ".$oDateTime->format("Y-m")."-01 09:00:00";
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare to the datetime directly:

```
WHERE date_field >= '2011-05-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TIMESTAMPDIFF function in MySQL to compare time,
FROM_UNIXTIME function to format Unix timestamp as date.

More mysql data and time functions and examples are available in [MySQL Reference Manual date and time function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) .

Answer (score 0):

`DATETIME` fields can filtered just like integer fields, example:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` > '2011-05-01 09:00:00'
```

In case you really want to convert to Unix timestamps, have a look at the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can solve it, something like this:

firstly, create first day of month in mysql format in php

```
$firsDay = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime(date('Y-m').'-01 00:00:00'));
```

and then, use it in the query

```
select * from something where date >= $firsDay
```